# TypeError: bodyParser.json is not a function in nuxt.js

Tags: express, nuxt.js, body-parser, nuxtjs

I have received an error message stating:  TypeError: bodyParser.json is not a function.  My nuxt.config.js file has the following details regarding bodyparser  (I originally had const bodyParser = require('body-parser') but an error appeared telling me that I had to use 'import' instead of 'require' so I changed it to 'import('body-parser'):

```
const bodyParser = import('body-parser')

export default {
  serverMiddleware: [
bodyParser.json(),
'~/api'
]
}
```

In my index.js file under the api folder, I have the following code:

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

const router = express.Router()

const app = express()
router.use((req, res, next) => {
  Object.setPrototypeOf(req, app.request)
  Object.setPrototypeOf(res, app.response)
  req.res = res
  res.req = req
  next()

  app.use(bodyParser.json())
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
})

router.post('/track-data', (req, res) => {
  console.log('Stored data!', req.body.data)
  res.status(200).json({ message: 'Success!' })
})

module.exports = {
  path: '/api',
  handler: router
}
```

Does anyone know how to get this to run?  Everytime I enter 'npm run dev' in the terminal, I get the error 'TypeError: bodyParser.json is not a function'.

Answer (score 3):

I had a slightly similar issue and could solve it with this code, first i imported express in the config file, before i did it like you, with bodyParser, but got a deprecated warning, then i use it in the api folder, in the index file, like so:

```
// nuxt.config.js
import express from 'express';
export default {
  ssr: true,
  .......,
  .......,
  serverMiddleware: [
    express.json(),
    // Api middleware
    { path: '/api', handler: '~/api/index.js' },
  ]
} 

// ~/api/index.js
// Router setup for serverMiddleware
router.use((req, res, next) => {
  Object.setPrototypeOf(req, app.request);
  Object.setPrototypeOf(res, app.response);
  req.res = res;
  res.req = req;
  next();
});

export default {
  path: '/api',
  handler: router
};
```

hope it helps !

Comment: This has worked for me, dont forget to declare the variables in index.js, and putting the index in routes to the top, essentially becoming a middleware for other routes

`import express, { Router } from 'express'`
`const router = Router()`
`const app = express()`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with `nuxtjs` specifically, but after looking at [the nuxtjs module export docs](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/modules) it looks like your `require` inside your `index.js` should be a path to the file, rather than just the string `body-parser` which I have to imagine just gets processed something like an npm module if no path is supplied.

Additionally, at least in NodeJS and per [the MDN docs on export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) and [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import),  the syntax to import something that's exported with `export default` is `import { destructuredModuleName } from 'string/representing/relative/or/absolute/path/to/module'`

or

`import * as whatYouWantToCallTheObject from 'string/representing/relative/or/absolute/path/to/module'` would give you a more traditional module object with properties/methods matching properties on the exported module.

Answer (score 0):

This should fix it:

```
import bodyParser from 'body-parser'
```

---

You actually used the `import()` as a [dynamic import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#dynamic_imports). It returned a promise which didn't have the `json` property. Therefore, the error was displayed.